# How to configure single broker for confluent control center

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

For develop purpose, I want to setup control center for my single broker kafka, but it was failed because of the exception. I put my configurations and control center output log details [here](https://github.com/AlvinYueChao/TroubleShoutings/tree/master/confluent%20single%20broker%20control%20center%20cannot%20be%20started). Could anyone help advise on it ?

```
[2020-04-04 11:27:55,883] ERROR [main] 3 brokers are required but only found 1. Check the topic replication settings in the properties file or add more brokers to your cluster (io.confluent.controlcenter.KafkaHelper)
```

Comment: please, include in the post the relevant information from your setup and logs in order to be able to understand the question without having to visit external sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Confluent Control Center to use a single broker for its topics. By default it's configured to require three to prevent possible data loss

In your [`control-center-production.properties`](https://github.com/AlvinYueChao/TroubleShoutings/blob/master/confluent%20single%20broker%20control%20center%20cannot%20be%20started/control-center-production.properties#L42) set:

```
confluent.controlcenter.internal.topics.replication=1
confluent.controlcenter.command.topic.replication=1
confluent.monitoring.interceptor.topic.replication=1
confluent.metrics.topic.replication=1
```

Comment: It's my bad, I forgot to uncomment the confluent.controlcenter.internal.topics.replication, thanks for your help, Robin.

Comment: `control-center-production.properties` is the default file indeed. I would have thought it would be `control-center.properties`, but no. that's an awkward default setting to default to production.

Answer (score 0):

change the service configuration confluent-control-center.service file in "/lib/system/system"

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/control-center-start /etc/confluent-control-center/control-center-minimal.properties
```